# Where's the location of the app/binary defined in a yocto recipe?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

I have a following recipe which runs a said service which in turns runs an app on boot-up, but I am trying to understand where the location of the app defined which ends up in sysfs image.

Currently, the `appSource` binary (defined in `Makefile`) gets stored in `/usr/bin` but I'm not sure where the destination location (`/usr/bin`) is defined.

The following command results in

```
$ bitbake -e appSource | grep ^FILES_${PN}

FILES_appSource="/usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* /usr/libexec/* /usr/lib/lib*.so.*             /etc /com /var             /bin/* /sbin/*             /lib/*.so.*             /lib/udev /usr/lib/udev             /lib/udev /usr/lib/udev
```

Here's the recipe

```
inherit autotools-brokensep pkgconfig

DESCRIPTION = "A sample recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS = "glib-2.0"

FILESPATH =+ "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = "file://appSource"
S = "${WORKDIR}/appSource""

FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_unitdir}/*"

INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"

do_install_append() {   
   if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'systemd', 'true', 'false', d)}; then
      install -d ${D}/etc/initscripts
      install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
      install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/appService/appService.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/appService.service
      install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/
      ln -sf ${systemd_unitdir}/system/appService.service  ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/appService.service
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I find out:

You are `inherit`ing `autotools-brokensep` which has the following content:

```bash
# Autotools class for recipes where separate build dir doesn't work
# Ideally we should fix software so it does work. Standard autotools supports
# this.
inherit autotools
B = "${S}"
```

So, it `inherit` `autotools` which has `do_install` with the content of:

```bash
autotools_do_install() {
    oe_runmake 'DESTDIR=${D}' install
    # Info dir listing isn't interesting at this point so remove it if it exists.
    if [ -e "${D}${infodir}/dir" ]; then
        rm -f ${D}${infodir}/dir
    fi
}
```

So, it runs the `install` target of your `Makefile` into `${D}` which is `${WORKDIR}/image`.

So, I assume that your `Makefile` has an `install` target that copies the binary into `/usr/bin`.

For the `FILES` variable content, this is defined in `bitbake.conf`:

```bash
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/* ${sbindir}/* ${libexecdir}/* ${libdir}/lib*${SOLIBS} \ ...
```

Provide your `Makefile` to confirm my assumption, or I do a further research on the topic.

Comment: I do have `bin_PROGRAMS = appSource` in `Makefile` and `bin_PROGRAMS` tells that the resulting binary is installed in `bindir` i.e `/usr/bin`. Is that it?